# Command line argument parsing in Haskell that supports shared arguments

Tags: haskell, command-line

We are currently using `System.Console.CmdArgs` to parse command line arguments. However, we are not entirely satisfied with the way that things are done right now. There is a lot of shared options between subcommands -- for example, the username, start date, and end date, etc.

Is there a Haskell command line parsing library that either supports "inheritance", or can take a list of subcommand entry functions and automatically derive a parser? Our goal is to avoid boiler plate, of which we have a lot right now.

Some example of our subcommands:

```
sum-payments [--start] [--end] [user]
list-users-seen [--start] [--end]
sum-queries [--start] [--end]
```

All subcommands support the `start` and `end` option, and the default is always "beginning of time" and "to now". Each subcommand might have its own options or positional arguments.

Comment: An illustrative example of the commands you're trying to parse would be useful, here.

Comment: SO isn't the place to request library recommendations.

Comment: ...so instead, you describe the problem, your current solution and the brick wall you face, and someone can suggest using a different library if that's an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what you can do with `optparse-applicative`.

Note how the `startEnd` parser is used inside of the `listUsers` parser.  The `startEnd` parser may be used in any other parser which needs a start and end option.

```
import Options.Applicative

data StartEnd = StartEnd String String
  deriving (Show)

data ListUsers = ListUsers { user :: String, bounds :: StartEnd }
  deriving (Show)

startEnd :: Parser StartEnd
startEnd = StartEnd
  <$> strOption ( long "start" )
  <*> strOption ( long "end" )

listUsers :: Parser ListUsers
listUsers = ListUsers <$> strOption ( long "user") <*> startEnd

doListUsers :: ListUsers -> IO ()
doListUsers lusers = print lusers

main :: IO ()
main = execParser opts >>= doListUsers
  where
    opts = info (helper <*> listUsers)
      ( fullDesc
     <> progDesc "Print a greeting for TARGET"
     <> header "hello - a test for optparse-applicative" )
```